# PDO SQLSTATE[42000] on simple select query

Tags: php, pdo

Im just new with programming in OOP, so im writing a function but it gives an error, i think im using PDO wrong, actually i now it for sure, but i dont now how to fix it. This is my code im using currently:

```
  public function takedrugs($soort, $hoeveelheid, $id){

    $conn = $this->conn;

    $drugsophalen = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM gebruikers WHERE id=:id');
    $drugsophalen->execute(array(':id'  => $id));

    $result = $drugsophalen->fetch();
    $huidigdrugs = $result[$soort];

    if($huidigdrugs >= $hoeveelheid){
      //Voldoende drugs dus drugs afnemen
      $drugsafnemen = $conn->prepare('UPDATE gebruikers   
                                     SET :soort = :soort - :hoeveelheid,
                                     WHERE id = :id'); 

      $drugsafnemen->execute(array(
                ':soort'  => $soort,
                ':hoeveelheid'  => $hoeveelheid,
                ':id'  => $id));


    } else {
      return false;
    }

  }
```

So when i use this function i get an error, its all about the SET :soort = :soort - :hoeveelheid.

This is the error i get:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
> 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''Cannabis' =
> 'Cannabis' - '2000', WHERE id ' at line 2' in

I hope there are some people who now how to fix it since i dont :S

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You CANT bind column names SEE Complex Cases in [**PDO info**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info).
Also as Jason states about lazy binding use `bindParam` OR `bindValue`

TRY

```
$drugsafnemen = $conn->prepare('UPDATE gebruikers   
                                 SET $soort = $soort - :hoeveelheid,
                                 WHERE id = :id'); 
$drugsafnemen->bindParam(':hoeveelheid', $hoeveelheid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$drugsafnemen->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$drugsafnemen->execute();
```

Comment: But in your code you still bindparam :soort to $soort while you dont use :soort in your code? Why is that or is that just a fail?

Comment: And btw i still get this error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined' in

Comment: Sorry my Typo(Beware Cut& Paste) see EDIT

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

First, by using [`execute()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) all your values are being treated as a *string*. This results in the syntax error:

```
UPDATE gebruikers SET field = 'Cannabis' - '2000' ...
```

I assume this is not your intention. Instead, use [`bindParam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) so you can define these parameters as integers.

```
$drugsafnemen->bindParam(':soort', $soort, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Second, you should are setting the column name dynamically (`:soort`). As such, it too is getting interpolated with `$soort`, which is probably not your intention.

Comment: Normally i just do it with an Array in the execute and that worked fine for all thing i did till now on. Which things do i have to bindparam and which can i also just execute array?

Comment: Anything that should be bound with a data-type other than string.

Comment: I get this error when i made :soort with bindparam. 
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' in /inc/class.user.inc.php:214 Stack trace: #0 /inc/class.user.inc.php(214): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 /test.php(14): User->takedrugs('Cannabis', 2000, 1) #2 {main} thrown in /inc/class.user.inc.php on line 214

Comment: You can't use both. It's one or the other. Either set your parameters with `bindParam` or `execute`.

Comment: That makes things clear, thanks. But now i get this error: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens' in /inc/class.user.inc.php:214 Stack trace: #0 /inc/class.user.inc.php(214): PDOStatement->execute() #1 /test.php(14): User->takedrugs('Cannabis', 2000, 1) #2 {main} thrown in /inc/class.user.inc.php on line 214

Comment: Read the errors: *number of bound variables does not match number of tokens*.

Comment: Im very bad in english, im sorry. But i dont get that error?

Comment: You need to ensure the number of parameters in your statement is equal to the number of parameters you bind.

Comment: But the other guy says you cant bind column names?